# Would a remote desktop created in this way work?

Tags: python, remote-desktop

I was thinking of using python to create a remote desktop program. There will be two parts to it, a server and a client. The server creates a connection between the client, the client then takes screenshots every second (or so), and sends them to the server. The server displays those screenshots, and mouse movements over the screenshots get translated to co-ordinates and get sent to the client. Mouse clicks and key presses, will also be sent to the client. This will effectively allow the server to control the client remotely. Obviously it will be a bit laggy, but will it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Imagine dragging a window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) which works the way you describe.